# how to supply default counts when grouping on strings that have not occurred yet?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a Result table that did a grouping on Section and Status in a Source table and produced this:

```
    Section        Status         Count


    C              Not Started        5
    D              Success            5
    D              Success            5
    M              Success            4
    M              Not Started       19
```

But in reality the Status can take on one of 4 values in the future, 'Not Started', 'Success', 'Failed' and 'In Progress'.  What is the simplest way to represent all the possible values for all the sections, and place a 0 as the Count when they were not yet in the Source table?  The sections will not grow in the future, they are fixed as 'C', 'D', or 'M'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have tables that already describe the possible statuses and
   the possible sections, then you add those two tables to your query
   and Left Outer Join both of them to the rest of your existing query.
2. If you do not have those tables in your data base then you'll have to create them inside your query.  Now the exact syntax for that varies from DB to DB, so you need to tag this question with the DBMS you are using before we go any further if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks I used this outline as follows:   I created a defaults table like this to fill in the gaps

defaults AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    ('C','failed', 0),
                 ('C', 'In Progress', 0) ,
                ('D', 'In Progress', 0) ,
                  ('M', 'In Progress', 0) ,
    ('D','failed', 0), 
    ('D', 'not started',0) , 
                ('M', 'failed', 0)            
           
  ) AS t (section,status, jobcount)
  ),

and then i  did a Union  and took the max(count).